# WinApi, ATL creating context menu function handler

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc, atl

The code below creates a window, implements a CListViewCtrl and tries to make a context menu with 3 options: new, edit & delete.

```
class CGuiView : public CWindowImpl<CGuiView, CListViewCtrl>
{
    HMENU hPopupMenu;
    MENUINFO m_ContextMenuInfo;

public:
    DECLARE_WND_CLASS(NULL)

    BOOL PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
    {
        pMsg;
        return FALSE;
    }

    BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CGuiView)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_PAINT, OnPaint)
    //  MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_LBUTTONUP,)
         MSG_WM_CONTEXTMENU(OnContextMenu) 
         COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(ID_CTXMENU_NEW, OnNewTask)
    END_MSG_MAP()


    LRESULT OnPaint(UINT /*uMsg*/, WPARAM /*wParam*/, LPARAM /*lParam*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
    {
        CPaintDC dc(m_hWnd);

        //TODO: Add your drawing code here

        return 0;
    }
     void OnContextMenu ( HWND hwndCtrl, CPoint ptClick )
    {


        hPopupMenu = CreatePopupMenu();

        InsertMenu(hPopupMenu,  0, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_STRING, ID_CTXMENU_DELETE, TEXT("Delete"));
        InsertMenu(hPopupMenu, ID_CTXMENU_DELETE, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_STRING, ID_CTXMENU_EDIT, TEXT("Edit"));
        InsertMenu(hPopupMenu, ID_CTXMENU_EDIT, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_STRING | MF_ENABLED, ID_CTXMENU_NEW , TEXT("New"));

        TrackPopupMenu(hPopupMenu, TPM_TOPALIGN | TPM_LEFTALIGN, ptClick.x, ptClick.y, 0,GetParent(), NULL); 


    }

    LRESULT OnNewTask(WORD /*wNotifyCode*/, WORD /*wID*/, HWND /*hWndCtl*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
    {

        CAboutDlg dlg;
        dlg.DoModal();
        return 0;
    }

};
```

The problem is that the code above does not enter OnNewTask when I click on the New menu item that I create in the OnContextMenu function. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are providing `GetParent()` as an argument to the `TrackPopupMenu` API function. So `WM_COMMAND` is sent to the list view parent, not list view itself.

Have it sent to the list view, or forward commands from parent to list view. You can also use Spy++ tool to check the messages in the debugged process to see what exactly is sent and where.